# jquery get last each if value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code,

```
$(function () {
    $.post("fetch_data.php?url="+$('#url').val(), { }, function(response){
        var arrValues = [ <?php echo $js_img_arr; ?> ]; //output from php

        $.each(arrValues, function( intIndex, objValue ) {
        var img = new Image(); //creating four Image Elements
            img.src = objValue;
            img.onload = function() {
            if(img.height > 100 && img.width > 200) {
                alert('height: ' + img.height + ' width: ' + img.width);
                //here
            }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am new to jquery/javascript.

Is it possible to get value of how many images loaded at last, let say 10 img have loaded and met the height/width criteria, i want the value of 10 images loaded.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $.post("fetch_data.php?url="+$('#url').val(), { }, function(response){
        var arrValues = [ <?php echo $js_img_arr; ?> ]; //output from php
        var length = 0; //counter variable 

        $.each(arrValues, function( intIndex, objValue ) {
        var img = new Image(); //creating four Image Elements
            img.src = objValue;
            img.onload = function() {
               length++;   //Increment the counter  by One
               if(img.height > 100 && img.width > 200) {
                   alert('height: ' + img.height + ' width: ' + img.width);
               }
            }

            alert('Number of Images loaded : '+ length); //Total number of Images
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `var arrValues = [ <?php echo $js_img_arr; ?> ];` will work as it is inside the callback function of the $.post method. the code inside

```
function(response){
  ....
}
```

will execute only after the ajax request is completed and a response is available which can be accessed using the 'response' parameter. you can decide in what form you want this response (xml, json , html, text etc) and then create the array `arrValues` accordingly.

What is your response btw. what are you echo-ing in the fetch_data.php file ?